# Wildcards without specific id, class

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make my corp system better for my usage so I write scripts but I struggle when it comes to dynamic names.

I want to change `#\\33 130\\:0` into `#\\** ****\\:*` but as I read in wildcards I need to specify it as `id=^`. I don't want to do that - I'd like to change only single characters which are constant, path does not change either.

```js
document.querySelector("#\\33 130\\:0 > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > div.slds-grid.bottomBar > div.bottomBarRight.slds-col--bump-left > button")
```

Previously this code was enough to click on the button, now XHR message appears in the console and it won't be clicked, thus I need full path now.

```
document.querySelector("div > div > div.slds-grid.bottomBar > div.bottomBarRight.slds-col--bump-left > button").Click()
```

Comment: See [id attribute documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id): *"Note: Technically, the value for an id attribute may contain any character, except whitespace characters. However, to avoid inadvertent errors, only ASCII letters, digits, '_', and '-' should be used and the value for an id attribute should start with a letter."*

Comment: why you have strange id `#\\33 130\\:0` or I miss something?

Comment: @uingtea this is not ID, but a part of it I guess. The system is weirdly written I think.

Answer (score 0):

CSS has no wildcard support at all, use something else

`[id*="56"][id*=" 12:0"]` may work mor some cases

General solutions:

- If there are many alike elements with alike paths, I try to find the needed one not with selector only, but by content

```
let qq = (s) => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(s))
list = qq('button').filter(e => e.innerText.includes('Confirm') )
// or
// set [data-text] attr
qq('button').forEach(e => e.dataset.text = e.innerText)
list = qq('button[data-text*="Confirm"]')
```

- Prefer `[id^="123 "][id$=" 36:0"]`-likes for IDs containing escapeable characters
- Generally try to use QuerySelectorAll to make sure your selector matches only one element (website changes may easily make old selectors match multiple elements)

```
fucntion clickOnly(sel) {
   let list = qq(sel); if (list.length == 1) list[0].click(); else alert(`multiple "${sel}" elements`)
}
```

- if you need to find elements with IDs and filter them, do it

```
// /^\d\d \d\d\d:\d$/ - RegExp matching `12 345:6` (\d for digit, ^$ for start/end of string)
list = qq('body > div > div[id]').filter(e=>e.id.match(/^\d\d \d\d\d:\d$/))
// flatMap: maps every `el` to `el[]`, and then flats `el[][]` into `el[]`
// `:scope` - targets current used element
list = list.flatMap(e => e.querySelectorAll(':scope > div > button'))
```

Also check if `Click` is named correctly, JS DOM functions are lowercase

Also note that to submit a form you may need to interact with page for scripted clicks to work

If you use Chrome Devtools, I recomment you to check out Sources(top tab) > Snippets(left tab) for saveable big chunks of code

If you can use userscript extensions and always run the same script for the same website (like, adding a keybinding for a button), I recommend trying `User JS And CSS` from Chrome extension store

Comment: Thank you however I need some wildcards in queryselector. ID are fully dynamic and change every time so I cannot use them. Only paths are more or less stable, some buttons have only different text property on it and that may be helpful.